# How to debug a failing Android Gradle build?

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle, aapt

My build fails like this (I haven't written this piece of software) on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
11:00:04.533 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
11:00:04.533 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
11:00:04.533 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:processArmv7DebugResources'.
11:00:04.534 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/xxx/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
11:00:04.534 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

So apparently running `aapt` fails. The problem is that this error obviously doesn't tell me anything. How can I find out what actually happened? I tried to run gradlew with --debug and --stacktrace with no luck.

Where is this task `processArmv7DebugResources` defined?

Comment: It seems like the issue with the build tool. Update the build tool and then do clean build.

Comment: Stupid question: how do I update it? I'm just running gradlew now.

Comment: I updated to build tools 24.0.2 but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you please share your build.gradle file information.

Comment: No, I can't because this is not open source :( That's why I asked how to debug this. There must be a way to see the actual `aapt` command...right? I can run `aapt` itself just fine but I don't know what arguments were tried when it failed.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a wrapper script called `aapt` that logs its arguments to a file and then calls the real `aapt`. This way I found out the actual command that caused the problem. It was something related to case sensitivity in asset file names that obviously had worked on Windows.

This was actually also printed by Gradle when called with --debug, but it was logged after the `aapt` crash and with Info tag so I wasn't sure if that's the root cause.